# Predicting a parameter using the estimates of a series of studies, using study location and year as random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, prediction, meta-analysis

I would like to ask whether my analysis design is correct.

I gathered all the trials on a series of drugs for a certain condition (second line therapy for advanced/metastatic lung cancer), published in the last 5 years.

For each drug used in the studies, I take the progression free survival (PFS) and the overall survival (OS). I want to predict the same outcomes in a specific country for each drug. (I know it's quite far fetched to have a realistic prediction, but I am more interested in the methodology).

For the analysis I run a mixed effect model (lme4::lmer in R) with the drugs as fixed effect and location of the trial and year of publication as random effect, weighting for the number of subjects in every study:

```
lmer(Val ~ Drug + (1 | Geo) + (1 | Year), data = Data, weights = Data$Num)
```

Then I would predict the effect for my country (in which some of those trial have been made) for the last 5 years and average the estimates by years, in order to have a predicted OS and PFS for each drug.

Is it a correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: You have added the tag meta-analysis. Usually in meta-analysis one would weight by the inverse of the sampling variances of the estimate (the thing you call Val). Is that what you want to do or do you not have them?

Comment: Indeed I don't have them. I thought of weighting for the number of observations in the studies assuming that the larger the number of people involved, the less propable is sampling bias.